Should I remove Audience from Power Bi app, if I started using RLS?
I have been using Power Bi App feature for certain dashboards and have been giving access to users directly from the Audience tab in Power BI App.
Now we've decided to restrict the access to certain data in the dashboards by creating and implementing RLS.
Now I have both: users added via app and users added via RLS.
Which one determines the access now, or which one is stronger, if the same user is added in both places? Or should I remove the users from app since they have been added via RLS?
I have added same users via RLS but can't tell if they will see everything (because they are also added in the App) or they will see whatever they have given the access according to their RLS.

App permissions give them access to reports.  RLS role membership gives them access to the data in the semantic model.  They should be in both.
